# Spring batch for processing large processing csv file

Tags: spring-batch

I have a 5gb CSV file that I am trying to process with Spring Batch (read, process, publish the data to JMS). What is the best way to go about this keeping in mind that NOT split the file into smaller files, and all records must be processed ? Does Spring Batch have the ability to process and write data while it is being streamed from the source? Is there any way to tell Spring Batch to read X lines from the file, process, and write (commit) and then grab the next X lines from the file while keeping track of which lines it has already processed

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is the basic feature of spring batch. Use commit-interval for this.
Suggest to read full detail here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html

Comment: Thanks for responding my question. I did large file to small files and my small files count is more than 5k. I want to apply 10 threads to process 5k files. here I did little bit but its processing 5k files at a time not 10 threads to 5k files. Here is my code.

Comment: <job id="transformerJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
  <batch:step id="splitMultipleFiles" next="TransformStep">
   <batch:tasklet>
    <batch:chunk reader="largeCSVReader" writer="smallCSVWriter"
     commit-interval="10000" />
   </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
  <batch:step id="TransformStep" >
   <batch:partition partitioner="transformPartitioner"
    handler="partitionHandler" />
  </batch:step>
  <batch:step id="deleteOutputFiles">
   <batch:tasklet ref="outputFileDeletingTasklet" />
  </batch:step>
 </job>

Comment: <bean id="partitionHandler"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler">
  <property name="taskExecutor" ref="batchTaskExecutor" />
  <property name="step" ref="jobExecutor" />
  <property name="gridSize" value="${thread.count}" />
 </bean>

Comment: <step id="jobExecutor" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
  <tasklet>
   <chunk reader="loadTransformData" processor="processTransformData"
    writer="flatFileItemWriter" commit-interval="${smallFile.records.count}" />
  </tasklet>
 </step>

Comment: Multiresource partitioner:Multiresource partitioner:public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {int index = 0;File directory = new File(outputPath);
  File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
  Map result = new HashMap(gridSize);
  for (File file : fList) {
    ExecutionContext exContext = new ExecutionContext();    
    exContext.put(ECDCConstants.THREAD_NAME, "Thread" + index);
    exContext.put(ECDCConstants.OUTPUT_FILE, outputPath + file.getName());    
    result.put(ECDCConstants.PARTITION + index, exContext);
    index++;
   }
  }

Comment: is there a specific reason why you want to use partitioner??

Comment: whatever value you have put for smallFile.records.count it will process that many records at a time.

Comment: <job id="transformerJob" xmlns="springframework.org/schema/batch">
<batch:step id="processFile"> 
 <batch:tasklet> 
  <batch:chunk reader="csvReader" processor="csvProcessor" writer="csvWriter" commit-interval="5000" /> 
 </batch:tasklet> 
</batch:step> 
</job>